# Automatic Bad Request Response in OpenAPI specification

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle

When a action has the attribute `[ApiController]`, ASP.NET Core return automatically `BadRequest` when parameters are invalided : 
[Automatic HTTP 400 responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#automatic-http-400-responses)

But this response isn't present in the Open API Specification generate by **Swashbuckle**.

I started to write a `OperationFilter` to detect when automatic bad request is enable like this :

```cs
public class AutoBadRequestResponseOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    void IOperationFilter.Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var autoValidate = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors.Any(d => d.Filter.GetType().Name == "ModelStateInvalidFilterFactory");
        if(autoValidate)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But it's use reflection on internal type of ASP.NET Core. Do you know a alternative that use public API?

Comment: Well, may I know how are calling this `AutoBadRequestResponseOperationFilter? You can introduce a custom attribute or metadata to explicitly indicate that automatic bad request handling is enabled for a particular action and then you can used on top of your controller. Have you tried that ?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, what do you call metadata?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, for the first question, it's called by Swashbuckle.

Comment: Oh I see, actually I pointed callling that CustomAttribute in order to check what exactly happening within the response, which I am calling the meta data for bad request. But as it from Swashbuckle then need to have a look if that allows overriding because few of the swagger methods allows that.